# Superscript Citation Within Endnote Appearing on Line By Itself

Tags: biblatex, citing, memoir, enotez

I am using biblatex with the memoir class, using the oxnum style so that citations appear as superscript numerals. I am also using the enotez package for endnotes. (These are generally longer text passages, not necessarily having to do with bibliographic citations.) I have defined a command \qattribute which I use at the end of quotations to put the author and title there in the body of the text, and include the citation referring to the more complete bibliographic entry. Most of the time this behaves as desired. However, whenever I have a quotation within an endnote, the superscript citation numeral does not appear next to the title as it should. Instead it appears below on a line by itself.

[image: Lonely citation numeral (not page number) 3]

I don't understand why \autocite is behaving differently in the endnotes than in the main text.

I have made an MWE, with a quotation in the body of the text and a quotation within an endnote. Here is my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{hang}
\setlength\hangingleftmargin{0.2\textwidth}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name={Endnotes},list-heading={\chapter*{#1}},counter-format=alph,backref=true}
\renewcommand*{\theendnote}{\alph{endnote}}
\usepackage[%
    autocite    = superscript,
    backend     = bibtex,
    sorting     = none,
    style       = oxnum,
    backref     = true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand\qattribute[3][]{%
    \par\begin{hangingpar}--\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2{#3}}{#2, \textit{#1}{#3}}\end{hangingpar}\vskip\onelineskip}
\renewcommand\bibname{Endnotes}
\begin{document}
This enthusiasm is not necessarily spectacular or showy, but a discerning observer or participant can perceive a deep wellspring flowing from teacher to student:
                                                    \begin{quotation}
\noindent{}Students gravitate toward teachers with whom they have forged a connection.\end{quotation}
                            \protect\qattribute[Excellent
                                    Sheep]%
{William Deresiewicz}%
{\protect\autocite{C108179}}
                        \par\noindent{}


These two departments had been at odds for thirty years.\protect\endnote{\begin{quotation}
\noindent{}

What we’re saying is that the company in the past has been locked in.…If we’re going to work on the total needs of the customer…there has to be a way that that’s seen in a lot of different places in the company.
                                                                            \end{quotation}
\protect\qattribute[The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization]%
                                        {Peter M. Senge}%
{}{\protect\autocite{C108184}}
\par\noindent{}                         }
                            \autocite{C108185}

\printbibliography[title={References}]
\backmatter
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Here is the accompany BibTeX file MWE.bib:

```
@book{C108179,
author={William Deresiewicz},
title={Excellent Sheep},
publisher={Free Press, division of Simon and Schuster Inc},
year={2014},
}
@book{C108184,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
pages={pp. 264–5},
annote={},
}
@book{C108185,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
}
```

How I can get the citation numerals to appear next to the titles on quotation attributions in the endnotes, as they do in the main text?

Comment: The code (and its alignment) looks a bit confusing to me, so I'm not sure I understand what is going on. But I did notice that in the first `\qattribute` call the argument following the author is `{\protect\autocite{C108179}}`, whereas in the second call it is an empty pair of curly braces followed by the cite: `{}{\protect\autocite{C108184}}`. This means that in the first case the `\autocite` is argument `#3`., but in the second call it is not an argument at all, so it will just follow the `\qattribute` as normal.

Comment: BTW: It appears to me that you could do away with some of the `\protect`s if you defined your commands to be protected in the first place. All the `\noindent`s and explicit `\par`s also look pretty odd.

Comment: `biblatex` also defines the commands `\citetitle` and `\citeauthor` to obtain the title and author of a work, so you don't have to type it in manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spurious `{}`, likely due to the strange formatting you use:

```
\protect\qattribute[The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization]%
                                        {Peter M. Senge}%
{}{\protect\autocite{C108184}}
```

You see the `{}` at the beginning of the last line.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{C108179,
author={William Deresiewicz},
title={Excellent Sheep},
publisher={Free Press, division of Simon and Schuster Inc},
year={2014},
}
@book{C108184,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
pages={pp. 264–5},
annote={},
}
@book{C108185,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{hang}
\usepackage{enotez}

\usepackage[%
    autocite    = superscript,
%    backend     = bibtex,
    sorting     = none,
    style       = oxnum,
    backref     = true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\setlength\hangingleftmargin{0.2\textwidth}
\setenotez{list-name={Endnotes},list-heading={\chapter*{#1}},counter-format=alph,backref=true}
\renewcommand*{\theendnote}{\alph{endnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\qattribute[3][]{%
    \par\begin{hangingpar}
    --\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2{#3}}{#2, \textit{#1}{#3}}
    \end{hangingpar}\vspace{\onelineskip}}

%\renewcommand\bibname{Endnotes}

\begin{document}

This enthusiasm is not necessarily spectacular or showy, but a discerning 
observer or participant can perceive a deep wellspring flowing from teacher to student:
\begin{quotation}
\noindent{}Students gravitate toward teachers with whom they have forged a connection.
\end{quotation}
\qattribute[Excellent Sheep]{William Deresiewicz}{\autocite{C108179}}


These two departments had been at odds for thirty years.\endnote{%
  \begin{quotation}
  \noindent{}What we’re saying is that the company in the past has been locked in.…
  If we’re going to work on the total needs of the customer…
  there has to be a way that that’s seen in a lot of different places in the company.
  \end{quotation}
  \qattribute[The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization]%
             {Peter M. Senge}{\autocite{C108184}}%
}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\backmatter
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

You also need no `\protect`.

[image]

A different implementation, that simplifies the input.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{C108179,
author={William Deresiewicz},
title={Excellent Sheep},
publisher={Free Press, division of Simon and Schuster Inc},
year={2014},
}
@book{C108184,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
pages={pp. 264–5},
annote={},
}
@book{C108185,
author={Peter M. Senge},
title={The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization},
address={New York},
publisher={Doubleday},
year={1990},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{hang}
\usepackage{enotez}

\usepackage[%
    autocite    = superscript,
%    backend     = bibtex,
    sorting     = none,
    style       = oxnum,
    backref     = true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\setlength\hangingleftmargin{0.2\textwidth}
\setenotez{list-name={Endnotes},list-heading={\chapter*{#1}},counter-format=alph,backref=true}
\renewcommand*{\theendnote}{\alph{endnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nicequote}{momm}{%
  \begin{quotation}\noindent\ignorespaces #1\end{quotation}
  \begin{hangingpar}
  --%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{#3{#4}}{#3, \textit{#2}{#4}}%
  \end{hangingpar}
  \vspace{\onelineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

This enthusiasm is not necessarily spectacular or showy, but a discerning 
observer or participant can perceive a deep wellspring flowing from teacher to student:
\nicequote{
  Students gravitate toward teachers with whom they have forged a connection.
}
[Excellent Sheep]{William Deresiewicz}{\autocite{C108179}}


These two departments had been at odds for thirty years.\endnote{%
  \nicequote{
    What we’re saying is that the company in the past has been locked in.…
    If we’re going to work on the total needs of the customer…
    there has to be a way that that’s seen in a lot of different places in the company.
  }
  [The Fifth Discipline: The Art {\symbol{38}} Practice of The Learning Organization]%
  {Peter M. Senge}{\autocite{C108184}}%
}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\backmatter
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.

I'm generating LaTeX files from XML files using python (and guile).  Your answer led me to the offending lines in my python script, which led me to this git log message I made on January 1, 2022:

    "Made the superscript reference appear next to the attribution of a quote, except if it is in an endnote."

I don't now recall why I made that exception. It was to solve some problem (which was also the reason for all the \protect's). Apparently something else I did in the meantime solved the original problem. Now I removed the exception and the output looks fine.

Comment: I will try using your \nicequote command too.  Thank you very much!